# Get Value from Parcelable Array in Android

Tags: android, parsing, parcelable

I need to parse and get the Value from  :

```
Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
```

My goal is to get UUID from above Parcelable[]. How to achieve it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the docs it states that the extra is a [ParcelUuid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelUuid.html)

So you should use

```
ParcelUuid uuidExtra intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
UUID uuid = uuidExtra.getUuid();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Throwing Error in Second Line @Ian Warwick

Comment: @Venky, since you marked it as the answer, is it now working and how did you get it to work?

Comment: this solution did not working. how can you accept an not working example

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this.  It worked for me:

```
   if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
     BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
     Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
     for (int i=0; i<uuidExtra.length; i++) {
       out.append("\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device + ", Service: " + uuidExtra[i].toString());
     }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over the Parcelable[], cast each Parcelable to ParcelUuid and use ParcelUuid.getUuid() to get the UUIDs. While you can use toString() on the Parcelables as in another answer, this will give you only a String representing the UUID, not an UUID Object.

```
Parcelable[] uuids = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
if (uuids != null) {
    for (Parcelable parcelable : uuids) {
        ParcelUuid parcelUuid = (ParcelUuid) parcelable;
        UUID uuid = parcelUuid.getUuid();
        Log.d("ParcelUuidTest", "uuid: " + uuid);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct in quoting the docs and saying that the returned object is of type ParcelUuid. However, he does not offer the link to that; here it is:
[BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_UUID).

Furthermore, the code provided is wrong in two ways; one, it does not refer to the same method as that of the question, and secondly, it's incompilable (taking some philological liberties here). To rectify both problems, the code should be:

```
Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
if (uuidExtra != null) {
   for (int j=0; j<uuidExtra.length; j++) {
      ParcelUuid extraUuidParcel = (ParcelUuid)uuidExtra[j];
      // put code here
   }
}
```

Thirdly, if one wants some extra protection (although, normally, the objects should always be `ParcelUuid`), the following can be used in the `for`:

```
   ParcelUuid extraUuidParcel = uuidExtra[j] instanceof ParcelUuid ? ((ParcelUuid) uuidExtra[j]) : null;
   if (extraUuidParcel != null) {
      // put code here
   }
```

This solution was offered by [Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564263/arne). I just cannot add comments yet, and plus I offer the documentation page :)